# click on Export to Excel button using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I want to click on Export to Excel button using selenium webdriver,but problem is the button is a Flash button and the html code for he same is commented out.So through selenium,web elemnt cant be identified.Below i have added the sample code for the Export button.And also its coresponding HTML code.Kindly help.

```
WebElement w1=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#leaderboard > div:nth-child(1) > div > span > div > span.pull-right.notification > a > span > span"));
    ////span[contains(text(),'Export')]
    JavascriptExecutor executor=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("argument[0].click()", w1);

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\LP-531\\Desktop\\window.exe");
```

HTML code for the same Export button:

```
<!--<span class="pull-right notification">
<a class="add-macro-text" href="javascript:void(0)">
<span class="add-macro">
<img class="add-macro-img" src="/chat-assignment/img/excel-icon.png" alt="Add Macro" />
<span class="export-to-excel-text">Export to Excel
</span></span></a>
</span>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot automate **Flash objects** using Selenium Web Element Locator's.

But we can achieve it by using Third Party Tools like *Sikuli*, *Autoit*,etc.

In my project I usually use *Sikuli* becuase i feel its implementation is easy to understand and use.

Now before you try with *Sikuli* or *Autoit* i would suggest to try below Locator's to detect the Flash Object with **Export to Excel** and see if it works.

**Try 1:**

```
WebElement w1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='export-to-excel-text']"));
```

**Try 2:**

```
WebElement w1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='add-macro']/span"));
```

**Try 3:**

```
WebElement w1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='add-macro-text']/span[1]/span"));
```

**Try 4:**

```
WebElement w1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='pull-right notification']//a[@class='add-macro-text']//span[@class='add-macro']//span[@class='export-to-excel-text']"));
```

Will be glad if any of the above works but if not then please refer below Links to ***Download Sikuli jar*** file and to ***Refer Sikuli Documentation***.

[Download Sikuli](https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download)

[Sikuli Documentation](http://doc.sikuli.org)

Comment: i understand that flash objects cant be identified,but problem here is with the click(as u mentioned ,findElement didnt work,as the html code for export to excel is hidden/commented out),so unless i am able to click on the button i am not able to proceed further.
After click,the windows button i able to automate using autoit,problem is with the click of button.
it would be great if you can help me with that.

Comment: Dipantu can you please specify when you say cannot click what it means and also help me with the error message you're getting?

Comment: please find text below
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: argument is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.155)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds

Comment: Now,below code runs fine,but export is not clicked and file even doesnt get created
WebElement w1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Export')]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",w1);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\LP-531\\Desktop\\window.exe");